# How to Build and test if a graph data structure is outputting the correct adjacency vertexes WITHOUT the use of lists or dictionaries

Tags: python, data-structures, graph-theory

I'm trying to build a graph data structure in Python, only something basic - but I'm having trouble testing if each vertex recognizes other vertexes are adjacent or not. I know how to do this with the use of Python lists and dictionaries however, I'm trying to use it without inbuilt lists or dictionaries - this time only with arrays and linked lists.

Any Suggestions How Id go about this or make sure it's working?

I've already got the basic graph down (nothing special) but I seriously have no idea how to get adjacent vertexes.

Comment: What do you refer to when saying "arrays"? Numpy arrays? *"I've already got the basic graph down"*: please add your code to your question.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. *"I've already got the basic graph down (nothing special) but I seriously have no idea how to get adjacent vertexes."* << Assuming you already have a basic data structure that represents the graph, then writing a function that can answer "are these two given vertices adjacent?" when given two vertices, will depend entirely on your data structure. Depending on the data structure it might be very easy or less easy. Anyway, no answer will make sense unless you actually show what your data structure looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There are two data structures frequently used for the design of graph data structures: adjacency matrix and adjacency lists.  Either makes it easy to determine if two vertices are adjacent.  If you are not using one or other of these, you should stop immediately and redesign your data structure.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparison-between-adjacency-list-and-adjacency-matrix-representation-of-graph/

There are many pitfalls in designing a feature full graph data structure and a great amount of testing is required.  So you should seriously using one of the many graph libraries available.